# Inner joining within an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I tried to find if there are any answered but couldn't seem to find any. I'm trying to join together four tables but one of the joins is not on the table that the other two joins are from, I've successfully joined three of the table I'm just not sure of syntax for joining the third.

```
SELECT * FROM 
nc_booking 
INNER JOIN
nc_customer ON nc_booking.c_id = nc_customer.id

INNER JOIN
nc_propertys ON nc_booking.p_id = nc_propertys.id
```

How would i now join nc_propertys to another table nc_owner?

Comment: if properties have owner id then you can join it with nc_owner

Comment: Although all the tables you joined so far connected with the `nc_booking` table, you don't need all joins to be like that. It can be more like a 'chain' and not like a 'star' if that's what you need and how the data is related.

Comment: Thanks, If i was trying to join another table to nc_booking I would just take a new line and write INNER JOIN etc, how do I go about exactly from joining from propertys in terms of what to actually write? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry not to respond sooner Niall. As you didn't tag me, I didn't realise you'd responded. Typing this from my phone, which isn't fun for code, so will attempt a proper response when back at a PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the code from @GordonLinoff, to add your extra table you need to do something like:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM nc_booking b INNER JOIN
      nc_customer c
      ON b.c_id = c.id INNER JOIN
      nc_propertys p
      ON b.p_id = p.id INNER JOIN
      nc_owner o
      ON o.id = p.o_id;
```

You haven't shared the column names we need to use to connect the extra table, so the last line might not be right. A few things to note ...

(1) The `SELECT *` is not ideal. If you only need particular columns here, list them. I've stuck with your `*` because I don't know what you want from the tables. Where a column with the same name exists in each table, you'll have "fully qualify" the field name as follows ...

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id,
       -- more field can go here, with a comma after each
       ...
```

Several of the joined tables have an `id` field, so the `c.` is necessary to tell the database which one we want. Notice that as with the tables, we can also give the fields an 'alias', which in this case is 'customer_id'. This can be very helpful for presentation, and is often essential when using the output from a query as part of a larger piece of code.

(2) Since all the joins are `INNER JOINS` it makes little (if any) difference what order the tables are listed as long as the connections between them remain the same.

(3) For MySQL, it technically shouldn't matter whether you have lots of new-lines or none at all. SQL is designed to ignore "white space" (except within data). What matters is simply laying out your code so it is easy to read ... especially for other users who later might need to figure out what you were doing (although in my experience also for you, when you return to a piece of code several years later and can't remember it at all).

(4) In each `ON` clause it doesn't actually matter whether you wright say a = b or b = a. That's because you aren't setting one to equal the other, you are requiring that they already be equal so it amounts to the same thing either way.

My advice to a SQL beginner would be when you are writing a `SELECT` query (which only reads and doesn't change any data): if you aren't too sure then write some code and set it to run. If it's completely invalid, your software should give you some idea of what is wrong and no harm will be done. If it's valid but wrong, the very worst that can happen is that you put some unnecessary load on your database server ... if it takes a long time to run and you weren't expecting it to, then you should be able to cancel the query. As long as you have some idea of what you expect the results to look like, and roughly how many rows to expect, you won't go too far wrong. If you get completely stuck come back here to Stack Overflow.

Things get a bit different if you are writing code which `DELETE`s or `UPDATE`s data. Then you want to know exactly what you're up to. Normally you can write a closely related `SELECT` statement first to make sure you're going to be making all and only the changes you were expecting. It's also best to make sure you've got a way to undo your changes should the worst happen. Backups are obviously good, and you can often create your own backup copy of a table before you make any alterations. You don't necessarily need to rely on backup software or your in house IT guys for that ... in my experience they don't like databases anyway.

Also there are some great books out there. For a beginner, I'd recommend anything by Ben Forta, including his *SQL in 10 Minutes* (that's a *per chapter* figure), or his *MySQL Crash Course* (the latter is a little old though, so won't have anything on the more recently added features of MySQL).

Comment: Steve, I can't thank you enough I really appreciate your help! I'll be sure to take your advice on board and i'm going to look into getting the book you have mention by Ben Forta! Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks okay.  I am providing an answer because you really should learn to use table aliases.  They make a query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT *
FROM nc_booking b INNER JOIN
     nc_customer c
     ON b.c_id = c.id INNER JOIN
     nc_propertys p
     ON b.p_id = p.id;
```

Comment: Thank you thats very helpful!